# refresh row number in kendo grid mvc

Tags: javascript, css, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I succeeded in showing the number of rows in the following two ways.

first way ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248005/css-auto-numbers-for-table-rows-not-first)) :

```
.ftable tr:not(.fble_htr) {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

.ftable tr:not(.fble_htr) td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

second way ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830920/kendo-ui-grid-show-row-number)):

```
<script>
    var counter = 1;

    function onDataBound(e) {
        counter = 1;
    }

    function renderNumber(data) {
        return counter++;
    }    
</script>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid()   
    .Name("Queue")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Template(t => { }).ClientTemplate("#= renderNumber(data) #").Title("#");
    })
    .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onDataBound"))
)
```

Kendo tables are usually in multiple pages. When I jump from page 1 to page 2, the row number is also refreshed, and the rows are numbered on page 2, from 1,2,3, ... . this problem existing in two ways

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/add-row-numbers

Comment: Is there a way to use the first way (css)?

Comment: I doubt it. CSS does not know anything about the content of your page, so it cannot make the required calculations.